# How to visualize JavaScript wrapper objects?

Tags: javascript, function, object, oop, primitive-types

Lately I read that for every primitive data type, a wrapper object is created. It is this wrapper object what makes it possible to use methods with that data, and that makes sense.

I also read that functions are objects. I found out that I can visualize the function-as-an-object through `console.dir()`.

However, when I apply `console.dir()` to a primitive data type, I get the value of the variable. But I was expecting to get an object, just as with functions. Is this because they are different cases? How can I access the wrapper object of a primitive data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `__proto__` property.
eg var a = 'something';
console.log(a.`__proto__`);
this is a deprecated feature though, the better way would be to use `Object.getPrototypeOf(<primitive here>)`.
take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) for more info about prototypes in js